# For $f,g:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $f$ continuous, $g$ measurable with $g(x)\in[0,1]$ a.e., show $\lim\int_0^1 f(g^n(x))dx$ exists and evaluate

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

For this question, I think of Jensen's inequality, as I believe for all $n$, $g^n(x)$ should be convex, and the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ gives a probability space. However, this does not seem to set us up well, as Jensen's inequality gives us $\int \phi(f(x))d\mu$ as a bound, where $\phi$ is our convex function.

Can we instead say that $f(x^n)$ is a convex function? I don't believe so, also, this would merely give us $f^n(\int g(x)dx)\leq\int f(g^n(x))dx$, again, not bounding what we want it to.

I am confident I should figure out some way to use Jensen's, as this is a probability space with some convex behavior, but I cannot figure out what that should be. Is there a different theorem I am not thinking of that works better?

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, hence bounded and $g(x) \in [0,1]$ a.e, you just need to see that $g^n(x)$ converges to 0 if $x \in g^{-1}[0,1)$ and to 1 if $x \in g^{-1}(1)$, then apply DMT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can not see the reason why Jensen will help here. Neither $g$ nor $f$ is told to be convex. We can use the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem).

Let $$A=\{x\in[0,1]: g(x)=1\}, B=\{x\in[0,1]: g(x)\in[0,1)\},$$
then $A, B$ are disjoint measurable sets and $m(A)+m(B)=m(A\cup B)=1$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. For $x\in A$, we have $g^n(x)=1$ for all $n$ and hence $f(g^n(x))=f(1)$ for all $n$; for $x\in B$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}g^n(x)=0$, hence by the continuity of $f$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(g^n(x))=f(0)$. Therefore, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(g^n(x))=f(1)\chi_{A}(x)+f(0)\chi_B(x),\qquad \text{a.e.}\quad x\in[0,1],\tag{$*$}$$
where $\chi_A$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the set $A$ defined by $\chi_A(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $\chi_A(x)=0$ if $x\notin A$.

On the other hand, since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, we know that $f$ is bounded, hence there exists $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, and thus
$$|f(g^n(x))|\leq M,\qquad \text{a.e.}\quad x\in[0,1], \quad\forall n.\tag{$**$}$$

Now it follows from the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f(g^n(x))\,dx&=\int_0^1f(1)\chi_{A}(x)+f(0)\chi_B(x)\,dx=f(1)m(A)+f(0)m(B)\\
&=f(1)m(A)+f(0)(1-m(A))\\
&=f(0)+(f(1)-f(0))\cdot m\left(\{x\in[0,1]: g(x)=1\}\right).
\end{align*}

Comment: Very nice, I was too distracted by Jensen's to realize the actual behavior of $g^n(x)$, this is perfect, thank you!

Comment: @cable You're welcome. I'm very glad to be helpful. Cheers! :-)

Comment: @Feng, very nice proof. Congratulations! Your ideas are always very good. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Angelo Thanks for you appreciation again! You are always so nice!

Comment: @Feng I believe as the OP just started studying measure theory & integration, a full solution to an easy exercise like this one would not help him much in this case...

Comment: @LNT You're definitely correct! It is a common issue in this site that people who are writing an answer hardly knows the background knowledge of the people who are asking a problem. As a consequence, every time when I'm writing an answer, I try my best to write as many details as possible, even though most of the time I have too many details to be liked here... Thanks for your nice comment!

Comment: @LNT I have been studying measure theory for 2 years, and "easy" is not well defined. This is a question from a qualifying exam that I failed as I had "gaps in understanding" and was able to answer the more advanced questions but none of the "simple" questions as this one. Complete solutions like this give me more insight into the  behavior and structure at play here. Sure, they could have said "it converges to an indicator function" and left it alone, but this is much more meaningful. This is likely the most helpful answer I have gotten to any question I have asked on this website.

Comment: @cable I'm very happy to see your comment. I will continue to write as detailed proofs as possible in the future, and strive to help more people. Come on! Prepare well for your qualifying exam and you will definitely pass!

Comment: @cable You said that you have been studying measure theory for 2 years then I believe that my comment would have sufficed for you to fill in the details. That process helps you relearn the basics, which is what I wanted to give. It's an easy exercise because many similar problems appear in most probability/analysis books. It is true that sometimes we forget the easiest stuff and ask but this problem, as you can see, is not complicated. Full solutions are not good for anyone, but if you feel it's helpful then I'm glad that Feng helped you better. Good luck with your exams! :).

Answer (score 2):

You do not need Jensen's inequality, the intuition should be simple - $g^n(x)$ converges to the indicator function of $A = \{x \in [0,1] | g(x) = 1\}$. Therefore
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int f(g^n(x))dx =_{(1)}\int f(\chi_A)dx=_{(2)}m(A)*f(1) + (1-m(A))*f(0)
$$

Equality (1) follows from the *Dominant Convergence Theorem*, since $f$ in continuous and the image of $g$ is compact, and equality $(2)$ follows from the fact that $f(\chi_A)=f(1)\chi_A + f(0)\chi_{A^C}$.

Comment: I was typing up your first sentence as you posted this, however, I was not picking up on (2). Thank you for that. Edit- (2) is obvious once I think about it, my bad.